# Ubuntu Bash: Get text between 2 colons from a text file

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am a beginner in Ubuntu bash and couldn´t find a solution after searching for hours.

I have a config file with lines like:

`u:TestUser:rw:/home/temp/testFolder`

I want to give the user the rights to this folder, but first I have to check if the user exists and if not, create that user.

The only problem I have is extracting "TestUser" from between the colons. With that I could check if the user exists with /etc/passwd.

Comment: `awk -F":" '{print $2}' config_file` would give you `TestUser`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "cut" the text between delimiters. A job for `cut`:

```
cut -d: -f2 /etc/passwd
```

- `-d:` - set's the delimeter to `:` (default is tab)
- `-f2` - will make `cut` print only the second field frim the file - ie. username

But to check if a user exists on a system, see [superuser - Find out if user name exists](https://superuser.com/questions/336275/find-out-if-user-name-exists) and use `id` command.

Comment: Ok thank you guys!